# Different font sizes rendered at select and input

Tags: html, css, browser

I observed a difference in rendered font size (tested on chrome and firefox, both with this behaviour) between `<select>` and `<textarea> + <input>` tags. Are there typical difficultys at the rendering select/option text?

I've set the identical font attribute values!

The first field is select, the text source is a `<option>` tag.

The second field is a textarea, the text source is the `placeholder` attribute.

[image]

Is there anything i can do to set both fonts on equal size?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh thanks, there where some words missing ;)